# Why does boiling hot dogs make the water dirty?

Tags: boiling, hot-dog

I boil some of my hot dogs and every time I do that the water becomes turbid. I am assuming that this water has salts and fat which makes it turbid. Do we know what is the composition of this water, does it contain nitrates, sodium?

Comment: Some of the best hot dog water is intentionally "dirty": https://eatsbythebeach.com/nyc-dirty-water-dogs-with-onion-sauce/

Answer (score 4):

Are there nitrates and sodium in the water? Absolutely, hot dogs are full of both. But the turbidity is primarily protein and fats. Sodium nitrate dissolves in water, and dissolved things don’t look turbid.